# how to save form data in our computer that was filled by vister on our webpage

Tags: html, css

i want to know how to save data of the visitor that was filled by the visitor on our website

```
        <ul class="form">               

            <li class="short">
                <label>First Name<span class="required"></span></label>
                <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="First Name" class="requiredField" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'First Name'; }" onfocus="if(this.value == 'First Name') { this.value = ''; }" />
            </li>
```

Comment: Typically you would use `fetch` to call an API on your sever to POST or PATCH the data from the web page. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data onto a program on your server. Usually you would use PHP, npm, python... but there are many options. It's not possible with only HTML or client side JavaScript alone unless you have them save the document and email it to you